# Change values within the component, that are assigned to component attributes

Tags: visualforce-component, attribute

I can't change controller variables *(myNumber)* within the component, that are assigned to **apex:attribute**s.

```
<apex:component controller="MyCtrl"> 
    <apex:attribute name="number" type="Integer" assignTo="{!myNumber}" description="" />

    <apex:outputPanel id="panel">

        {!myNumber}

        <apex:commandLink value="Increase" rerender="panel">
            <apex:param name="number" assignTo="{!myNumber}" value="{!myNumber + 1}" />
       </apex:commandLink>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:component>
```

The value does not increase by clicking the link. But as soon as I remove the **apex:attribute** tag, I can change the displayed value.
Any idea why? Any work around?

Comment: You could certainly fire some sort of event from the child in a change listener.